# Using S3 Links When Running Pig 0.14.0 in Local Mode?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, apache-pig

I'm running Pig 0.14 in local mode. I'm running simple scripts over data in S3. I'd like to refer to these files directly in these scripts, e.g.:

`x = LOAD 's3://bucket/path/to/file1.json' AS (...);
// Magic happens
STORE x INTO 's3://bucket/path/to/file2.json';`

However, when I use the following command line:

```
$PIG_HOME/bin/pig -x local -P $HOME/credentials.properties -f $HOME/script.pig
```

I get the following error:

`Failed Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
N/A mainplinks  MAP_ONLY    Message: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2118: Input path does not exist: s3://bucket/path/to/file.json
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat.getSplits(PigInputFormat.java:279)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:962)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:979)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$600(JobClient.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:897)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:850)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:850)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:824)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.jobcontrol.Job.submit(Job.java:378)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.jobcontrol.JobControl.startReadyJobs(JobControl.java:247)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop20.PigJobControl.mainLoopAction(PigJobControl.java:157)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop20.PigJobControl.run(PigJobControl.java:134)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher$1.run(MapReduceLauncher.java:276)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: s3://com.w2ogroup.analytics.soma.prod/airy/fb25b5c6/data/mainplinks.json
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:235)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:252)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat.getSplits(PigInputFormat.java:265)
    ... 20 more
    file:/tmp/temp-948194340/tmp-48450066,`

I can confirm that `LOAD` is failing; I suspect that `STORE` will fail too. `REGISTER` S3 links also fail. I can confirm that the links referenced by `LOAD` and `REGISTER` exist, and the links referred to by `STORE` don't, as Pig expects.

I've solved some issues already. For example, I dropped jets3t-0.7.1 into $PIG_HOME/lib, which fixed runtime errors due to the presence of S3 links at all. Additionally, I've provided the relevant AWS keys, and I can confirm that these keys work because I use them AWSCLI to do the same work.

If I use awscli to copy the files to local disk and rewrite the links to use the local file system, everything works fine. Thus, I'm convinced that the issue is S3-related.

How can I convince Pig to handle these S3 links properly?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the way Pig read from S3 is through HDFS. Furthermore, in order Pig to be able to access HDFS, Pig must not run locally. For setting up non-local Pig easily, I'd suggest you to spin up an [EMR cluster](https://aws.amazon.com/emr/) (which I have tried this on).

So first you need to setup your HDFS properly to access data from S3. 
On your `hdfs-site.xml` configuration, make sure to set values for `fs.s3a` keys:

```xml
<property>
  <name>fs.s3a.access.key</name>
  <value>{YOUR_ACCESS_KEY}</value>
  <description>AWS access key ID. Omit for Role-based authentication.</description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>fs.s3a.secret.key</name>
  <value>{YOUR_SECRET_KEY}</value>
  <description>AWS secret key. Omit for Role-based authentication.</description>
</property>
```

There should not be any need to restart HDFS service but there is no harm on doing so. To restart a service, run `initctl list` then `sudo stop <service name according to initctl output>`.

Verify that you can access S3 from HDFS by running (note the s3a protocol):

`$ hdfs dfs -ls s3a://bucket/path/to/file`

If you get no error then you are now able to use S3 path in Pig. Run Pig in either MapReduce or Tez mode:

`pig -x tez -f script.pig` or `pig -x mapreduce -f script.pig`.

https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/25578/how-to-access-data-files-stored-in-aws-s3-buckets.html